# Playframework Evolutions with JOOQ generator

Tags: playframework, sbt, jooq, playframework-evolutions

The project I work with uses `JOOQ` and its generator to generate classes from `Postgres` database. The database evolutions are managed by `Play Evolutions`. We also use `git` as revision control system. This set of tools cause sort of self referencing issue when fetching new evolutions/jooq code from `git`:

Evolutions of new tables created by other team members cannot be applied due to compilation issues caused by absence of `JOOQ` generated classes from these tables.

I was thinking of following solutions:

1. Apply evolutions from sbt - create sbt task - failed to implement so far,
2. Manually apply evolutions on db (copy paste script) - makes no sense.

Stack:

- PlayFramework 2.3.8
- Jooq 3.5.3
- Java 8

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to generate the code using SBT, prior to compilation.

Provided that there is an easy means to bootstrap the JOOQ code generator (for example by means of a static method, or by creating a generator instance), you could have a look [here](https://github.com/slick/slick-codegen-example/blob/master/project/Build.scala#L27) to see how to create a task that bootstraps the process.

Then, if you want the SBT task to be executed prior to compilation, you would do it like so (if you were to call the task `generateJOOQ`):

```
compileInputs in (Compile, compile) <<= (compileInputs in (Compile, compile)) dependsOn (generateJOOQ in Compile)
```

Having a JOOQ SBT plugin would make things easier, but I think the maintenance effort of creating such a plugin should not be underestimated because one needs to cater for different SBT versions and JOOQ versions.

Comment: Actually, I created a subproject with a script to run evolutions  programmatically and then invoke `Jooq generator`. I run the script prior to compilation.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a plugin.
When the application starts, the plugin applies the evolutions.

Comment: I am afraid application would not start as it has compilation issues.

Comment: From the talk of the creator of slick (and slick can generate classes from tables), he advises to always commit your generated classes for the model.

Comment: Aye, this is one of the possible solutions. However generated classes are exposed to edits and someone with JPA background could damage the project.